# Angular 2/4/5/6 - Multiple charts for chart.js in the same canvas

Tags: angular, canvas, angular5, chart.js, ngfor

**UPDATE**

I used primeng charts instead as a fix.

I initialised a chart object (data) and pushed it into an array of charts (dataArray).

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataArray; let i=index">
    <p-chart #chart type="pie" [data]="dataArray[i]" [options]="optionsArray[i]" width="600" height="600"></p-chart>
  </div>
```

Initial Question

How do you print multiple charts of chart.js in the same canvas?

**canvas.component.html**

```
<div>
   <canvas #canvas>{{charts}}</canvas>
</div>
```

**canvas.component.ts**

```
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

charts: Chart[] = []; //assume populated
@ViewChildren("canvas") canvas;

constructor(){}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.canvas); //gives me a query list?
}
```

**The query list looks like this:**

[image]

Similar issue here but solution not clear, would really appreciate your help!
[Chart.js + Angular 5 - create multiple dynamic charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497769/chart-js-angular-5-create-multiple-dynamic-charts/52588419#52588419)

Comment: Can you please share your code, if you got a solution. I'm Stuck With similar issue. Thanks

Comment: hey thripthi I've updated my answer! lemme know if you need further help :)

Comment: What is it missing on this "duplicate" question and answers?